# TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.2)

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Deployment Contract

```
const { network } = require("hardhat");
const { verify } = require("../utils/verify");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const { deploy, log } = deployments;
  const chainId = network.config.chainId;
  const args = [];

  const tx = await deploy("Box", {
    from: deployer,
    log: true,
    args: args,
    waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1,
    proxy: {
      proxyContract: "OpenZeppelinTransparentProxy",
      viaAdminContract: {
        name: "BoxProxyAdmin",
        artifact: "BoxProxyAdmin",
      },
    },
  });

  if (chainId !== 31337 && ETHRSCAN_API_KEY) {
    await verify(tx.address, args);
  }
};

module.exports.tags = ["all", "box"];
```

Deployment output

```
Nothing to compile
deploying "BoxProxyAdmin" (tx: 0x3e75f543c5fce27998b3db8da8710dfa6cb3a64cc20cbcf1541b4d3af5522308)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 787721 gas
deploying "Box_Implementation" (tx: 0xc6ef6b178e31307413c27d146431f5b34295b07dcfd76b026ed9444b4a24cb7b)...: deployed at 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 with 148453 gas
deploying "Box_Proxy" (tx: 0x17da665d221a8fba9cd057e3830fcce3a5132ad4ac56fac61c3b5e06bf4a73a3)...: deployed at 0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0 with 720722 gas
deploying "BoxV2" (tx: 0xa07304240e91382413087b000e741ed7c8cc63bead81762bde0bcb202620490b)...: deployed at 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9 with 191301 gas
Done in 1.87s.
```

scripts ( script is giving error mentioned above )

```
async function main() {
  const boxProxyAdmin = await ethers.getContract("BoxProxyAdmin");
  console.log(boxProxyAdmin.address);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(-1);
  });
```

Comment: Please, add the solution as an answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The Deploy script changed in the new hardhat version.
For example the old hardhat versions deploy script:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const Message = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("welcome");
  const contract = await Message.deploy();
  await contract.deployed();
  console.log(
    "Owner address: ",
    owner.address,
    " contract address: ",
    contract.address
  );
}
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

And the deploy script of the latest version (**"hardhat": "^2.16.1"**):

```
require("ethers");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  const contract = await ethers.deployContract("welcome");

  console.log("Contract address:", await contract.getAddress());
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Yah, got it Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it , Just changed the scripts as :

```js
const boxProxyAdmin = await ethers.getContract("BoxProxyAdmin");
const proxyAddress = await boxProxyAdmin.getAddress();
console.log(proxyAddress);
```